# Not able to get textAngular's model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textangular

I have use text-Angular.js for making my div as RTE and bind the data somewhere. Here is the code

```
<div text-angular="text-angular" ng-model="htmlcontent"></div>              
<div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getRTEText()">Get Text</div>
```

and on get Text I am using following line of code.

```
   $scope.getRTEText = function(){
        console.log($scope.htmlcontent);
   }
```

But I'm getting $scope.htmlcontent as undefined.
What I want is internal HTML. but I am unable to get it. I am new in angular JS. Please help.

Comment: What you acutely want to do?

Comment: Please add your complete view and controller.

Comment: I want HTML text inside the htmlcontent model

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer of using $parent scope but it did not work for me. Here is how I managed when I encountered this same issue and could not find an obvious solution.

I used the ng-change directive to call a function on change event and update the scope value.

```
<div text-angular="text-angular" ng-model="htmlcontent" ng-change="updateHtml(htmlcontent)"></div>
```

Then in your controller you have a function:

```
$scope.updateHtml = function(htmlcontent) {
  $scope.htmlcontent = htmlcontent;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just change to this

```
 <div text-angular="text-angular" ng-model="$parent.htmlcontent"></div>
```

It's a weird syntax, but it is necessary since $modal creates a child scope of ModalInstanceCtrl.